# Run tests programmatically with junit5

Tags: java, junit5

*(disclaimer: I know there is plenty of good tutorial about it, but I cant find exactly what I want).*

I am building a Java app that test a Docker infrastructure every X minutes, it parse docker-compose and test every container with dedicated tester class. I want to use `junit` as a framework (to generate report etc...).

The test part is running via a `picocli` command.

I tried to use `org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher` but it seems we cant specify class instance only `selectors` patterns:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
   .selectors(
     selectPackage("X.tester.runners"),
     selectClass("MyTestFactory")
    )
 .build();
```

whereas I have already the class instance to test (via Google Guice), I would like something:

```
class Test {
   @Inject stuff....

   void execute() {
      Assertions.assertEquals(....);
   }
}
```

```
List tests = Arrays.asList(injector.getInstance(Test.class).setPath("toto.yml")); // From Files.walk

new JupiterTestEngine().execute(tests);
```

Comment: `it seems we cant specify class instance`, sorry but I don't get this part.. Do you have junit tests launched right now? What do these tests do? What's exactly the point for the super factory here?

Comment: you are right, I tried to clarify